# How to add different soundtracks for separate animations

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio, actions

Using the `Action Editor` I created multiple animations/actions. I'm able to add sound to the animations using the `Video Sequencer` by following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UbEa_pXH_9E). Could someone let me know how to link different soundtracks to different animations in the same blender file?

Comment: Hello, could you please explain what do you mean by "link a soundtrack to an animation"?

Comment: Using the "Action Editor" I can save different Actions/animations. Using the "Video Sequencer" I can add sounds. But the sounds remain the same when I change the Action and I'd like to have different sounds for different animations. Perhaps I'm not thinking about this the right way -- is there a recommended way to save multiple animations with sound in Blender?

Comment: you can't link sounds to keyframes in the Dope Sheet itself, the Dope Sheet is made to create animation but it's in the Video Sequencer that you can add, cut, move, group video, image and sound strips

Comment: not sure if this is the best way to do it but i got something that works for us by (a) adding actions to the nonlinear animation editor (b) adding audio to the sequencer and syncing it to the animations (c) setting start and end frames manually for different animations (d) rendering animations

Comment: ah sure when you need to synch the animation to a sound you can put a sound into the VSE, but I don't think you can link a sound to some NLA strips or Dope Sheet keyframes from what I know